# NDB Query not returning full object

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am doing a NDB query, which seems to only be fetching a partial object.  For the Model, I've turned off caching, in case that was it.  However, a number of properties are coming back with None, when I can see them filled in the Datastore Viewer.

This is with the local development server ( and deployed), and the query is being done by a Backend process.

Note: Clearing the memcache did not help.

NOTE:  If I cause the backend to restart, it will start pulling down the correct data.

Basically:

Backend starts querying for instances of a Model every X seconds

Frontend causes a change to an instance of the Model

Backend continues to see the original version of the instance until restarted

Backend code is pretty simple:

```
while 1:
    time.sleep(2)
    q = None
    res = None
    q = core.Agent.query()
    res = q.fetch(10)
    for a in res:
        logging.error("%s" % a.to_dict())
```

Frontend changes some properties (and it shows in the viewer) but the backend will only show old values. It also seems like a Filter will filter based on correct values, but fetch() returns old stuff.

Comment: Are you pretty sure the frontend is changing properties of existing entities and not creating new entities? (If it were accidentally creating new entities, that could explain why you'd see new values but your program saw old values.) Maybe you could show the code that edits the entities? (Or just say "Nope, I checked and that's not happening".)

Comment: I only see the changed entities in the Datastore Viewer (only 2 entities for my testing)

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't make more sense to use the task queue? You could insert a task from the frontend whenever the entity is changed, rather than having a backend polling for changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the context cache at the top of the loop, e.g.

```
while 1:
  ndb.get_context().clear_cache()
  <rest of your code>
```